# Using a *.patch file to change a Linux kernel's source

Tags: linux, git, kernel, patch

I have been provided with a patch file for Linux kernel 3.18.3 and must use it with a custom Linux kernel scheduler. 
By default, it's used in "Debian GNU Linux Wheezy 7.8.2 (32bit) - linux 3.18.3". Details [here](http://moodle.epfl.ch/pluginfile.php/1599330/mod_resource/content/11/CS323%20-%20VirtualMachine.pdf).

But now, I want to use it with Linux kernel 3.18.3, downloaded from [kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/](http://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/).
I downloaded that kernel, copied the patch file to the `linux-3.18.3` folder, then ran `git apply dummy.patch` but this was not successful.

I've also been provided with the "config.txt" file. I tried to use the config file before using the patch file but got the same result.

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnkUs.png):

```
dummy.patch: trailing whitespace
...
error: patch failed: include/linux/sched.h:1167
error: include/linux/sched.h: patch does not apply
error: include/linux/sched/sysctl.h: No such file or directory
....
error: kernel/sched/sched.h: patch does not apply
```

Comment: Why are you using a `git apply` command? Also, can you link to the patch file as well?

Comment: You may try `--ignore-whitespace` or `--whitespace=warn` option of `git apply` or try running `patch -p0 < dummy.patch` command; but one of errors is about absent file, so I think the patch is not compatible with kernel.org's kernel without some other patch, which was used by debian.